# Using jmespath to concat two fields of json

Tags: json, jmespath

I have this inputJson:

```
[{"firstName": "Kancha", "lastName": "Cheena"},
{"firstName": "Harley", "lastName": "Quinn"}]
```

Expected output:

```
[{"fname":"Kancha", "value": "Kancha Cheena"},
{"fname":"Harley", "value": "Harley Quinn"}]
```

I am using an expression like this:

```
[*].{fname: firstName, value: firstName lastName}
```

Can you please suggest correcting this expression?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use jmespath expression like

```
[*].{"fullName":join(``, [firstName, lastName])}
```

Which gives following result

```
[
  {
    "fullName": "KanchaCheena"
  },
  {
    "fullName": "HarleyQuinn"
  }
]
```

First parameter for the join function is the separator

Comment: Should be with spaces 
[*].{"fullName":join(` `, [firstName, lastName])}